# Is there anyway to expand my MacBook Air's hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro

I have a 2011 MacBook Air(11-inch), I am using OS X 10.9, but I only have 64GB Flash Storage, and I  want to expand the storage of MacBook Air's hard disk. I asked geniuses at Apple and they told me the answer is no. So, is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible, although not from Apple themselves.

A company called OWC seem to specialise in SSD upgrades for macbook's and have upgrades for your model [available here](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Air-Retina/Apple-MacBook-Air-2011-Drive-Internal-Flash)

These particular upgrades offer greater speed and capacity to some of the stock apple SSD's from 2011.

Answer (score 0):

I might also recommend you check out a micro USB drive.  Kingston makes one called the DataTraveler micro.  It's very small and only protrudes out from the computer a little.  You can get them up to size 64GB currently.

Answer (score -2):

You could also ad a Nifty Drive to your mac. You plug that in your SD-Card reader (which is used by that then). http://eu.theniftyminidrive.com

It is slower than an SSD, but you could move some stuff over there.

Comment: 11" MacBook Airs don't have SD card readers -- only the 13" ones do